# How to Change specific value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm working with Angular 2+ and Material (https://material.angular.io).
I use the stepper to build a simple form.
It works pretty well, with the exception of the following case.
I want to change the value of the [stepcontrol] dynamically.

So I want change this:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]= "Form_1">
```

to this

```
<mat-step [stepControl]= "Form_1 && Form2">
```

when I press a button or do anything else.

**Edit:**

HTML

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
   <mat-step [stepControl]="Form1">   <-------!!!!!
      <ng-template matStepLabel>1 Step</ng-template>
      <form [formGroup]="Form1">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name1" formControlName="Name1" required>
         </mat-form-field>
         <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
         </div>
      </form>
      <form *ngif = " variable-x == 1" [formGroup]="Form2">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput placeholder="Name2" formControlName="Name2" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
         <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
   < a button to switch the value of variable x from 0 to 1>
   ---> Next Step ....
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

The two forms are validated in the TS file. The form2 is only displayed if the variable -x is 1.
Everything works, but not the stepcontrol.

The following is possible:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="Form1">
```

If Form1 is valid you can go to the next step. This Work

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="Form1 && Form2">
```

If Form1 AND Form2 is valid you can go to the next step. This Work

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="(Form1 && variable-x == 0 ) || (Form2 && Form1 && variable-x == 1)">
```

I actually want it like this:
It should only use Form2 as a condition if variable-x is equal to 1. Form2 can only filled out if it is visible, but it does not work.

Comment: Well, just write the condition: `[stepControl] = "Form_1 && (!condition || Form2)"`. What's inside these quotes is, basically, code. You can't easily change code dynamically in angular.

Comment: Or use `*ngIf`: `<mat-step [stepControl]="Form_1" *ngIf = "condition"> ... <mat-step [stepControl]="Form_1 && Form2" *ngIf = "!condition">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First to: "[stepControl] = "Form_1 && (!condition || Form2)". It works, but unfortunately it works only with conditions which are FormGroups. As in my example Form1 and Form2. So it does not work if I call a function that returns a true or false or if I query variable. My conditions always work reliably because they always work on <button [disabled] = "same conditions">. Your second recommendation works, but I have to duplicate too much code. So that's not a good solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

as a solution , you can set a `boolean` to check if the **button** (that you said) was clicked or not :

**in TS Code :**

```
btnClicked : boolean = false;
onButtonClick(){
   this.btnClicked = true;
}
```

**in Html Code :**

```
<mat-step *ngIf="!btnClicked" [stepControl]= "Form_1">
<mat-step *ngIf="btnClicked" [stepControl]= "Form_1 && Form2">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works, but unfortunately I have to duplicate too much code here. <mat-step *ngIf="!btnClicked" [stepControl]= "Form_1"> Code for Form1 <mat-step> <mat-step *ngIf="btnClicked" [stepControl]= "Form_1 && Form2"> Code for Form1   and Form2<mat-step>. The problem is that I still have a Form3. So I would need:  [stepControl]= "Form_1" &   [stepControl]= "Form_1 && Form2" & [stepControl]= "Form_1 && Form2 && Form3"

Comment: the third mat-step when it will be shown  ? i don't understand what you need exactly

Comment: I want to use multiple forms in a Mat step. First, only Form1 is displayed. Only Form1 should serve as a condition for the Stepcontrol. With a click on a button, you can also display Form2 in the same Mat step. If Form2 is displayed, it should beinclude as a condition in StepControl.

Comment: you can use a `counter` that counts the number of forms then use `*ngIf` to check this number to define your `stepControl`

Comment: see my start post. There is a Counter  "variable-x". This decides when Form2 should be displayed. But I do not want to take two steps out of one step. Since the structure is mixed.